# HuggingFace Transformers not getting installed in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, compiler-errors, huggingface-transformers

I'm new in VS code and in coding in general, I've been trying to install transformers with the command `pip install transformers` and `pip install transformers[tf-cpu]` both didn't work, with the following error:

```
Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\TevaJ\Desktop\Projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\TevaJ\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\TevaJ\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps54vamjd'
       cwd: C:\Users\TevaJ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kolpujzg\tokenizers_befed87ed1a749f8a23369cfa56db8a2
  Complete output (19 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\tokenizers
  copying tokenizers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\tokenizers
  running build_ext
  error: can't find Rust compiler

  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

  To update pip, run:

      pip install --upgrade pip

  and then retry package installation.

  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
(venv) PS C:\Users\TevaJ\Desktop\Projects>
```

I looked up on google but I can't find a solution.
Does anyone know this error and how to fix it?

Comment: There was a similar problem and was supposed solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69612259/14982837

Comment: The solution did not work. I've tried to look deeper with the links, on github huggingface, rustup, wheel, cartography... nothing worked.

Comment: Refer to [installation page](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation), try if one helps. or install it without dependencies by the command `pip install transformers=="3.1.0" --no-dependencies`.

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT  Unfortunately I need the dependencies for my researches... It did work to install transformers with your command tho.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

Just had to install it from source without dependencies with PIP 619.

```
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git 
cd transformers
pip install -e .
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution - is install Rust compiler, make a restart and try pip install again.

Comment: I guess it's not working either way, probably some packages/versions incompatible together. Been trying to solve it since couple days and i can't find a proper way to do so. Scraping the financial news hasn't been easy with the new transformers...

Answer (score 0):

I try the following command.It works

```
conda install -c huggingface transformers
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot install Transformers version >2.3.0 with pip, try installing using conda instead, after installing rust compiler.

"conda install transformers" or "conda install -c huggingface transformers"